# Issues with extracting substrings of a string in Python Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have an expression like ( one row of a column, say '**old_col**' in pandas data frame) ( **Shown the top two rows from a column of the dataframe** )

abcd_6.9_uuu ghaha_12.8 _sksks

abcd_5.2_uuu ghaha_13.9 _sksks

I was trying to use the str.extract on the dataframe to get the two floating numbers. However I find two issues, only the first one is picked up( 6.9 from first row and 5.2 from second row )

***1.*** So how can I do that?

***2.*** Also how can I make the extract method general to pick numbers upto any digits ( 5.7or 12.9 irrespective)

I am using:
df['**newcol**'] = df['**old_col**'].str.extract('(_\d.\d)')

Answer (score 3):

To get more than one digit,

```
df['col'].str.extract('(\_\d+\.\d+)')

    col
0   _6.9
1   _15.9
```

To get all occurrences, use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html)

```
df['col'].str.extractall('(\_\d+\.\d+)')

            col
    match   
0   0      _6.9
    1     _12.8
1   0     _15.9
    1     _13.9
```

To assign back to df:

```
s = df['col'].str.extractall('(\_\d+\.\d+)')['col']
df['new_col'] = s.groupby(s.index.get_level_values(0)).agg(list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much RafaelC.. However when I use your extractall method, I get an error: 
TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index

Comment: The extract method is working fine to get the first one.. But the extractall is not workinng

Comment: Not sure how this error would be raised. Are you running *exactly* the code I posted or are you trying to assign back this value to the df? Check edited..

Comment: I am trying to run: df['new_col'] = df['col'].str.extractall('(\_\d+\.\d+)')

Comment: Actually I am trying to put the two values from each row as two separate columns or at the the least in one column as x.y_a.c ( in this example, I will like a column as   row1_-> 6.9_12.8 and row2 -> 15.9_13.9

Comment: Instead of grouping, you can simply use stack and then assign to two columns. something like df[['f1','f2']]=df['col'].str.extractall('(\d+.\d+?)').unstack() +1

Comment: Vaishali, you solution does not seem to be working as I get the error:  "Could not operate 1 with block values must be str, not int"

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Series.str.findall`:

```py
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'old_col':['abcd_6.9_uuu ghaha_12.8 _sksks','abcd_5.2_uuu ghaha_13.9 _sksks']})
df['newcol'] = df['old_col'].str.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?')
df['newcol_str'] = df['old_col'].str.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?').str.join(', ')
# >>> df
#                           old_col       newcol newcol_str
# 0  abcd_6.9_uuu ghaha_12.8 _sksks  [6.9, 12.8]  6.9, 12.8
# 1  abcd_5.2_uuu ghaha_13.9 _sksks  [5.2, 13.9]  5.2, 13.9
```

**Regex details**:

- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits followed with an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `\d+\.\d+` would **match only float values** where the `.` is obligatory between at least two digits.

Since `.str.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?')` returns a list, the `newcol` column contains lists, with `.str.join(', ')`, the `newcol_str` column contains strings with found matches merged.

If you must check if the numbers occur between underscores add them on both sides of the pattern and wrap the number matching pattern with parentheses:

```py
.str.findall(r'_(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)_')
```